# Why is $X^4+1$ reducible over $\mathbb F_p$ with $p \geq 3,$ prime

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

I have proven that in $\mathbb F_{p^2}^*$ exists an element $\alpha$ with $\alpha^8 = 1$.

> Let $f(X) := X^4+1 \in \mathbb F_p[X]$. How can I prove that $f$ is reducible over $\mathbb F_p$?

Has $f$ a zero in $\mathbb F_p$ ?

Comment: Is that *some* $\,p\,$ or it can be **any** prime $\,p\,$ ?

Comment: just $p \neq 2$.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what exactly is the question here: the equation $\, x^8=1\,$ has **always** solution in $\,\Bbb F_{p^2}^*\,$ since this last is an abelian group of even order. Are you arguing then that $\,x^4+1\,$ is **always** reducible modulo *any* odd prime $\,p\,$ ?

Comment: Yes, thats what the question states.

Comment: So $X^4+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb F_3$ ?

Comment: $x^4+1=x^4-2x^2+1-(-2)x^2=(x^2-1)^2-x^2=(x^2-1+x)(x^2-1-x)$ mod $3$. One thing is having a root another is being irreducible.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think I know, finally!, what you meant with this exercise. Be sure you can follow and prove all the following:

**Claim:** $\,x^4+1\in\Bbb F_p[x]\,$ is reducible for *any* prime $\,p\,$

**Proof :** For $\,p=2\,$ the claim follows from $\,x^4+1=(x+1)^4\bmod 2\,$ , so let us suppose $\,p\,$ is odd.

Note that for any such prime, $\,p^2-1=0\bmod 8\,$ (why?) , so that the cyclic multiplicative group $\,\Bbb F_{p^2}^*\,$ has a cyclic subgroup of order $\;8\;$ , and from here that you have an element *of order* $\,8\,$ in $\,\Bbb F_{p^2}^*\;$ (and not merely an element s.t. $\,\alpha^8=1\,$ , which is completely trivial). Since

$$x^8-1=(x^4+1)(x^4-1)$$

over any field, all the roots of the right hand side are contained in $\;\Bbb F_{p^2}^*\;$ , and since this is an extension of degree two over the prime field $\,\Bbb F_p\,$ (and observe that $\,x^4+1\,$ is **always** a polynomial over this prime field!), it cannot be this polynomial is **irreducible** over the prime field since then any of its roots would form an extension of $\,\Bbb F_p\,$ of degree $\;4\;$ , which is absurd. $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\square\;$

Comment: Hmmm...would it be too much to ask for a little explanation about the downvote here? Thanks.

Comment: We have that $\alpha$ is a zero of $X^4+1$. If $X^4+1$ would be irreducible it would be the minimum polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb F_p$ and thus $[\mathbb F_p(\alpha) : \mathbb F_p] = 4$ which cannot be true since $\mathbb F_{p^2} : \mathbb F_p(\alpha)$ is a field extension and thus this degree must be $\leq 2$.

Comment: Exactly @Andre. I wonder whether the downvoter thought something of what I wrote is wrong or else he was upset for seeing the answer...oh, well.

Comment: I don't know. Your answer helped me the most. Thanks. One remark: Is it the true $\alpha^4 = -1$ since $(\alpha^4)^2 = 1$ and $\alpha^4 \neq 1$ ?

Comment: Yes...why? Because the equation $\,x^2=1\,$ has only two solutions on any field of characteristic$\neq 2\;:\;1\,,\,-1\,$ , so if $\,x=\alpha^4\;$ ,then $\,x^2=1\;\wedge\;x\neq 1\implies x=-1\,$

Comment: Just for clarity. Thanks :)

Comment: @DonAntonio : I understand this except the idea of choosing $8$ :O could you please explain what made this $8$ to be the obvious choice....

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik, the original question mentions the equation $\;x^8-1=0\;$ . Since the roots of unity of order $\;2n\;$ have arather close relation to those of order $\;n\;$ (can you see it?...:) ), I guess I tried that...

Comment: @DonAntonio : I remember seeing somewhere relation between roots of unity of order 2n and of order n though could not actually state it... I would think for some more time.. :) If you have a copy of Dummit foote Abstract algebra I would request you to see that once.. It was mentioned with out any reason to consider $x^8-1$ (He might have mentioned but i could not realize it).. Corollary 16 of Chapter 14; Galois theory..

Comment: Oh, no, no @PraphullaKoushik. There is a rather **good, explained** reason there to do that. Read it...it says that $\;p^2-1=0\pmod 8\implies (x^8-1)\mid (x^{p^2-1}-1)\;$ and from here all rolls down.

Comment: @DonAntonio : Oh yes yes.. I understand that except that it took so much time for me to realize... :)

Comment: This is the most beautiful proof I have read before of this problem.

Answer (score 16):

We can use three different factorizations:

If $2$ is a square mod $p$. (which occurs for $p=\pm1$ mod $8$)

$x^4+1=x^4+2x^2+1-2x^2=(x^2+1)^2-2x^2$ Assume $q^2=2$ mod $p$. Then $x^4+1=(x^2+1+qx)(x^2+1-qx)$.

If $-2$ is a square mod $8$. (which occurs for $p=1$ or $3$ mod $8$)

$x^4+1=x^4-2x^2+1+2x^2=(x^2-1)^2-(-2)x^2=(x^2-1+rx)(x^2-1-rx)$, where $r^2=-2$ mod $8$.

Finally, if $-1$ is a square mod $8$. (which happens for $p=1$ mod $4$)

$x^4+1=x^4-(-1)=(x^2+r)(x^2-r)$, where $r^2=-1$ mod $p$.

Checking if all the cases are covered.

All (odd) primes are congruent to either $1,3,5,7$ mod $8$. The cases $1$ and $7$ are covered by the first factorization. The case $3$ by the second. The case $5$ by the third, since $p=5$ mod $8$ implies $p=1$ mod $4$.

Comment: We need $\left(\frac2p\right)=\left(\frac{-1}p\right)=1$. But,$$\left(\frac2p\right)=1\iff p\equiv1,7\pmod 8\text{ and }\left(\frac{-1}p\right)=1\iff p\equiv1\pmod 4$$ (http://www.mathreference.com/num-mod,qr12.html), but what about $p\equiv3,5\pmod 8?$

Comment: $p=5$ mod $8$ is inside $p=1$ mod $4$. The case $p=3$ mod $8$ is covered by the factorization that uses that $-2$ is a square mod $p$.

Comment: @frankin, got you point. We need $\left(\frac2p\right)=1\text{ or } \left(\frac{-2}p\right)=1$ or both

Comment: +1. We don't even need to know specifically for which primes $2, -2, -1$ are squares. If neither $2$ nor $-1$ is a square, their product certainly is (uses only that the multiplicative group is cyclic). The claim doesn't even require $p\ge 3$ as in fact $X^4+1=(X^2+1)^2$ over $\mathbb F_2$.