# Is $x^4-1$ reducible over every $\mathbb{F}_p$ for every prime p?

Tags: abstract-algebra, prime-numbers, irreducible-polynomials

Is $x^4-1$ reducible over every $\mathbb{F}_p$ for every prime p? I think I need to split into the cases of $p=2$ and $p$ being odd, but not idea how to proceed from there...

Comment: This is trivial, as Igor's factorization shows. Did you perhaps mean $x^4 + 1$? In that case, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427439/why-is-x41-reducible-over-mathbb-f-p-with-p-geq-3-prime

Answer (score 4):

Yes, because $x^4 - 1 = (x-1)(x^3 + x^2 + x + 1).$

Comment: So how does show that it is reducible over any $\mathbb{F}_p$?

Comment: Because I factored it over every $\mathbb{F}_p?$

Comment: Oh I see... this seems to be a trivial question then... Thanks