# Prove or disprove that $X^4+1$ is irreducible in $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p\mathbb{Z}}[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

As the title says: I want t prove or disprove the irreducibility of $X^4+1$ in $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p\mathbb{Z}}[X]$, $ p$ prime.

I have already proven that $X^4+1$ can't have linear factors in $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p\mathbb{Z}}[X]$, since it doesn't have roots in $\mathbb{Z}.$ By contradiction, such a root $k$ with $k^4=-1$ would have order $8$ which can't be since $8 \not| p$.

But that still leaves the possibility of a nontrivial decomposition with quadratic factors. So say $X^4+1 = (a_1x^2+q_1)(a_2X^2+q_2) \implies a_1a_2 = 1, a_1q_2+a_2q_1 = 0, q_1q_2 =0$. My hunch is that there is a contradiction somewhere in this equations, but I can't find it. Maybe there is none?

Comment: $X^4 + 1 = (X + 1)^4$ over $\Bbb Z/(2)$

Comment: $x^4+1$ is a square over $\mathbb{F}_2$, and for any odd prime $p$, the degree of the splitting field of $x^4+1=\Phi_8(x)$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ is given by the least $k$ such that $8\mid (p^k-1)$. It follows that $x^4+1$ completely factors over $\mathbb{F}_p$ if $p\equiv 1\pmod{8}$ and factors as the product of two quadratic irreducible polynomials otherwise; it is never irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p$, despite being irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $p=2$ we have "freshman's dream"
$$
x^4+1=(x+1)^4,
$$
so it is certainly not irreducible. For $p=3$ we have
$$
x^4+1=(x^2 + 2x + 2)(x^2 + x + 2).
$$
In general see this duplicate:

[Why is $X^4+1$ reducible over $\mathbb F_p$ with $p \geq 3,$ prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427439/why-is-x41-reducible-over-mathbb-f-p-with-p-geq-3-prime)

Comment: Is there a way to prove this for general prime $p$?

Comment: Yes, there is, and it has been asked before.

Comment: One followup question though: Why is it true that if $-1$ and $2$ are not squares in $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p\mathbb{Z}}$ then $-2$ is a square?

Comment: Okay I figured that one out: Let $x$ be a generator. $\exists n$ odd such that $x^n =-1$,$ m $ odd with $x^m = 2$ $\implies x^{n+m} = -2$ must be a square , since $m+n$ is even.

Comment: Yes, you could also use the Legendre symbol, i.e., $(-2/p)=(-1/p)(2/p)=(-1)^2=1$.