# Determine which finite field $F$ must contain so that the splitting field of $F$ over $t^4+1$ is equal to $F $

Tags: field-theory, splitting-field

This questions is a follow up - but not a duplicate - of this post

[Why is $X^4+1$ reducible over $\mathbb F_p$ with $p \geq 3,$ prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427439/why-is-x41-reducible-over-mathbb-f-p-with-p-geq-3-prime)

> Let $F $ be a field of characteristic $p >0$. Show that $f = t^4+1 \in F[t] $ is not irreducible. Let $K$ be a splitting field of $f $ over $F$. Determine which finite field $F $ must contain so that $K=F $.

As mentioned before,  the first part of the question is already answered. But how can I answer the 2nd one, especially as $f $ can have sifferent factorizations?

Answer (score 1):

This is a corollary to Don Antonio's answer to your previous question.  The answer is $\Bbb{F}_p$ if $p=2$ or $p\equiv 1 \pmod8$ and $\Bbb{F}_{p^2}$ otherwise, since (for $p$ odd) it's always the smallest extension field that contains primitive 8th roots of unity, which for a finite field is equivalent to having size congruent to 1 mod 8 since its non-zero elements form a cyclic group under multiplication.

If $p$ is even, then $p=2$ and you can do that case by inspection.